# Calculating points on the curve

Tags: geometry, bezier-curve

I want to get the x and y coordinates of a curve..How can i do that...

[image]

In the above image.Is it possible to calculate the intermediate points(one side) by knowing starting and ending point

Comment: At least you have to have a model for the curve, and knowledge of extremities will let you pin down parameters of that model. Without the model, your question is incomplete.

Comment: To add to Sasha: are you assuming it's a circle arc? A Bézier arc? What?

Comment: I just point out the arc. I know starting point(i.e)top left and ending point (i.e)Bottom left. It is a bezier arc..

Comment: Then your problem is underdetermined. Remember that a Bézier arc requires four control points to determine it.

Comment: Ok...if it's is a parabolic arc...is is possible to find x and y coordinates..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I surely observe that the given curve on the bi-concave lens is a parabola ,
so take the coordinate axes ,and then fix the lens at origin ,so that the mid-point(center) of the lens coincide with the origin ,

so then eccentricity of the lens is known or can be calculated,so one can find each corresponding $y$ for each $x$,

for more details about parabola see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola)

Comment: Actually this one seems to be a programmatic and mathematical question...My curve is an image that shown above...so i can't trac the exact curve..there will be free space infront of curve where the arrows are placed....

Comment: oh,fantastic ,i just now read about you,i felt very happy that you are a good programmer,and all the best for your iphone project,@anish

Comment: may be if you are interested in programming i suggest you to join this too,: http://superuser.com/, there are many people,programmers there,with whom you can share and exchange your knowledge,thank you

Comment: How can you "surely observe that the given curve on the bi-concave lens is a parabola"? According to Wikipedia (granted, not the most authoritative source) "[most lenses are spherical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_(optics)#Construction_of_simple_lenses)" so even if we knew that the picture represents a bi-concave lens (which is still a reasonable guess), a circle arc would be more likely (and, again, a guess).